# Help to identify a small tube part

Tags: part-identification

I'd like some help identifying the black parts circled in the photo.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a piece of [3mm rigid hose](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=hose%203mm&brand=1000&tab=P). It looks something like this:

[image]

That particular piece must have been cut from a larger piece, as the smallest it has ever come is 3L (3 studs) and never black at that size.

It's debated if cutting tube pieces is a purist thing to do or not.

Comment: Cutting rigid hose is allowed in my opinion as The Sears Tower Architecture model (21003) had it as an actual step in the instructions.

Comment: It was the Space Needle set I believe, 21003-1